# stationary time series example

Tags: time-series

Please, could anyone give an example of a stationary time series? I mean, if for instance $x_{1}$, $x_{2}$, $x_{3}$, $x_{4}$, $x_{5}$ are the 5 first random variables of the series, what would be the joint distribution of ($x_{1}$, $x_{2}$,$x_{3}$, $x_{4}$, $x_{5}$)? And then what would be the joint distribution of ($x_{1}$, $x_{2}$)? And for $x_{1}$?

Comment: Do you use statistical software? Because you could probably benefit a lot from running a few simulations yourself and then doing a little exploratory analysis first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x_1)$ be the (marginal) density of the first random variable and $f(x_t)$ the t-period marginal density,
then the joint distribution $f(x_1,x_2)\equiv f(x_2|x_1)f(x_1)$. 
Thus the overall joint is:
$f(x_5,...,x_1) = f(x_5|x_1,...,x_4)f(x_4|x_1,x_2,x_3)f(x_3|x_1,x_2)f(x_2|x_1)f(x_1)$